# Controlling two AC devices, device turning on incorrectly

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, code-review

I am making use of the code below to control the speed of an AC fan and the intensity of an AC Lamp with an Uno.

The problem I am having is that, when I set the lamp intensity to low or medium, the fan turns on at a very low speed as well, and I cannot turn it off even when setting the fan to off.

Also if I turn the lamp on and then off, the fan (which is still set as off), will spin slowly for a second or two in random intervals.

For troubleshooting purposes, I did separate this program into two programs, controlling each device and its circuit separately, and it works perfectly, but when I combine them, I get the above problem.

Any assistance in troubleshooting or ideas to solve this would be appreciated.
Haven't attempted AC control before.

```
int PWM = 3;
int FAN = 4;
int dimming;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial connection started, waiting for instructions…n0 =     Offn1 = 25%n2 =50%n3 = 75%n4 = 100%");
  pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FAN, OUTPUT);

  attachInterrupt(0, zero_crosss_int, RISING);
}

void zero_crosss_int()
// function to be fired at the zero crossing to dim the light
{
  int dimtime = (75 * dimming);  // For 60Hz =>65
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);    // Off cycle
  digitalWrite(FAN, HIGH);   // triac firing
  delayMicroseconds(10);         // triac On propogation delay
  //(for 60Hz use 8.33)
  digitalWrite(FAN, LOW);    // triac Off
}


void loop ()
{
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char ser = Serial.read(); //read serial as a character


    switch (ser)
{

  /* Lamp Control  */

  case '0':
    analogWrite(PWM, 0);  //lamp Off
    break;
  case '1':
    analogWrite(PWM, 50);  //lamp low
    break;

  case '2':
    analogWrite(PWM, 130); //lamp medium
    break;

  case '3':
    analogWrite(PWM, 255); //lamp high
    break;

  /* Fan Control  */


  case '4':
    dimming = 128;  //fan off
    break;

  case '5':
    dimming = 90; //fan low
    break;

  case '6':
    dimming = 65; //fan medium
    break;

  case '7':
    dimming = 35; //fan high
    break;

  default:
    Serial.println("Invalid entry");

    }
  }
}
```

The circuits it controls is based on these :

Lamp
[image: PWM AC Lamp]

Fan
[image: Dimmer AC Fan]

Also, these circuits and code are based on these post, if it may interest you:

Lamp
[PWM AC Lamp](https://diyhacking.com/arduino-lamp-dimmer/)

Fan
[Dimmer AC Fan](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/dimmer-arduino/)

Comment: `dimming` should be volatile.

Comment: I was advised that. Tried it and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Suppose you have conditions under which the problem manifests itself. Please tell me what will happen if you disconnect the lamp manually.

Comment: If the lamp is disconnected, I still get the same issue . In fact, disconnecting  the lamp circuit completely from the Arduino, I still get the fan randomly spinning for a short burst if I set the lamp to turn on at low or medium with the code. It's almost as if the PWM signal is controlling the fan or interfering

Comment: By the end of interrupt processing, all others are blocked. The function zero_crosss_int() takes too much time. This can cause problems with the built-in function and the base code. Try to move the part that specifies the time interval outside the interrupt handler.Or schedule a timer for these purposes.
Also, I wonder why you use two different circuit-based principles for similar tasks in one design?

Comment: I simply wanted to attempt to control the AC devices in two different ways, although they are similar. Do you know how I can implement a timer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of the zero_crosss_int() ISR is unreliable. After each interrupt it unconditionally turns on the triac, even in the OFF position. Since the `dimming` value in that case is close to the AC cycle duration, it may miss the current cycle and turn on early in the next cycle. This may happen e.g. due to noise in zero crossing input.

75 us * 128 = 9.6 ms. Assuming 50 Hz AC, cycle duration is 1000 ms / 100 = 10 ms. You only have 4% margin.

You need to avoid turning on the triac close to the end of the AC cycle. Limit the maximum value of `dimming` variable to, say, 75% of the AC cycle. This will impose a lower limit on the output power. However, you want to do this anyway because motors need a minimum power to start rotating. Adjust the ISR so that in the OFF position it does not send a positive pulse at all.

ADDED: so you just need to add an `if` statement to you ISR code:

```
void zero_crosss_int()
// function to be fired at the zero crossing to dim the light
{
  if (dimming > 96) // choose this value experimentally, adding some margin
    return;
  ... everything else goes here ...
}
```

ADDED2: Blocking for extended duration in the ISR is not a good idea in general. If you happen to need to do anything else in addition to 'dimming' a fan, you will almost certainly need to get rid of this. You could start a timer in the ISR and send the output pulse in the timer ISR, making sure that the timer ISR does not get executed after the next zero-crossing ISR...

Comment: I added the if (dimming > 96) condition, and that fixed the problem! The Fan is no longer turning on if I switch the lamp on at low intensity. However, the IFR830 Mosfet used in the circuit to control the lamp is now heating up, just noticed it melting a jumper cable. Did not experience this before.

Comment: Well, what wattage is on the lamp?

Comment: It is a 70w bulb. And just to correct a typo, it is IRF830 Mosfet.

Comment: Yes it is quite strange. It seems like the Drain pin was the one heating up (breadboard melted around it). I really thought I found a solution with the if statement so this is disappointing. Could you explain what is meant by underdriven. Sort of learning all of this along the way.

Comment: @Imraan: are you doing 220V on a breadboard? I cannot advise on a circuit that works on the line voltage.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I'm using a breadboard because that's the only thing available to me. I'm hoping to take a drive down this week to an electronics store to try and get a circuit board. I was advised a breadboard should be fine for testing purposes and for what its worth I have managed to implement this project safely, apart from the incorrect fan behavior I was experiencing due to the zero cross.

Answer (score 2):

Imraan, you have most definitely NOT build your circuit safely as to do so is impossible on a 'breadboard' when using 220 VAC.  The contacts on these boards are extremely poor not to mention that the separation between the metal contacts is inadequate.  Please read up on track separation for mains voltages on PCB's to get an idea of what is required.
The commonly used 0.1" pitch strip board is also unsuitable for mains voltages.